# How to tag code in C# XML documentation

Tags: c#, xml, documentation, xml-documentation

I have this function:

```
public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> strings, string separator)
{
    return string.Join(separator, strings.ToArray());
}
```

which I want to document.
I want the `<return>` tag to say `string.Join(separator, strings.ToArray())` since to anyone able to read C# code this says more than a thousand words. However, when I use

```
<return>string.Join(separator, strings.ToArray())</return>
```

then string.Join(separator, strings.ToArray()) will be formatted as plain text, which makes it almost unreadable. So I tried

```
<return><code>string.Join(separator, strings.ToArray())</code></return>
```

but this always creates a new paragraph...

So here's my question:
Is there a way to format a piece of text so that it appears as if it were code? I'd be satisfied with a fixed-width font.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The <c> tag sounds like it's what you're looking for.  Check out MSDN's [tag reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for more details.

That said, are you sure you want the documentation to refer directly to the actions performed by the function?  What if you decide to change the implementation later?  I know this is a pretty trivial example, but food for thought! :)